# Parse error on pattern matching rexpMatch function

Tags: rascal

I am trying to pass a regex argument as string and use that string with rexpMatch().
However it looks like the rexpMatch does not support escape characters.
Is there a workaround for rascal v0.18.2?

code snippet below:

```
    import String;

    public bool Match(str line, str reg)
    {
        return rexpMatch(line, reg);
    }

    Match(".", "\.");
```

result: Parse error

Answer (score 0):

In Rascal regexps are not strings, not even values, so you can't pass them around.

Regexps can appear at arbitrary positions in patterns. So if you want to encapsulate a regex as a value, the only way is to wrap them in a function, lambda or closure, and then pass the function to the other function.

Example:

```
bool isCapitals(/^[A-Z]+$/) = true;
default bool isCapitals(str _) = false;
 
bool findMatch(value v, bool (str) matcher) {
    visit (v) {
        case str s : if (matcher(s)) return true;
    }

    return false;
}

// Try it
findMatch(["no", "YES"], isCapitals);
```

Comment: Indeed I got the message that you cannot pass regex around. However, the signature of rexpMatch(str s, str re) suggests otherwise. And the function does work with regex string as long as no escape characters are used. So to me it seems like a bug in the function. e.g. rexpMatch("abc", ".*") does work.

Comment: Aha! Thanks for explaining; I'll have a look in the code tomorrow and check to see the documentation makes sense. I thought rexpMatch was your own code 

Comment: `return values.bool(Pattern.matches(re.getValue(), s.getValue()));` this is the implementation of rexpMatch, which means the regex goes into the Java Pattern class directly after Rascal has de-escaped and de-quoted the contents of the string. This means the syntax of the regexp as a Rascal string is almost the same as if it were a Java string. The extra escapes are for \< and \>.